# Prove that if $0\leq a,b$ and $a+b=1$ then $x^ay^b\leq ax+by$ for $x, y >0$

Tags: inequality

Would like help getting started, unfamiliar with proving inequalities in general.

Comment: This is known as Weighted AM-GM Inequality. Check out proofs [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/204352/how-does-this-prove-am-gm) and [here](https://www.math.ualberta.ca/pi/issue4/page20-24.pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is a simple and pretty form of a very widely-used result, so it is worth looking at it from many different points of view. here is one -

suppose $b  \in (0,1]$. let $s$ denote a real variable on $[1,\infty)$. and consider the function:
$$
f(s) = 1 + b(s-1) - s^b
$$
clearly $f(1)=0$. and we have
$$
f'(s) = b(1-s^{b-1}) \ge 0
$$
with the inequality strict if $s \gt 1$.

this means that $f \ge 0 $, which we may write as:
$$
s^b \le 1- b + bs \tag{1}
$$
suppose $y \ge x \gt 0$ and set $s=\frac{y}{x}$. then (1) becomes:
$$
\left(\frac{y}{x} \right)^b \le (1-b) + b\left(\frac{y}{x} \right)
$$
multiplying both sides by $x$ now gives:
$$
x^{1-b}y^b \le (1-b)x + by
$$
writing $a$ for $1-b$ gives the result required

Answer (score 2):

Consider, $f(x)=\log(x)$. Then $f''(x)=-\frac{1}{x^2}<0$. So, $f$ is concave function. Since $a+b=1$ so, using Jensen's inequality ,

$$f(ax+by)\ge af(x)+bf(y).$$

$$\implies \log(ax+by)\ge a\log x+b\log y$$

$$\implies ax+by\ge x^ay^b.$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Concavity of logarithms.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Jensen's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality):

$f(\frac{\sum_i a_i x_i}{\sum_i a_i})  \geq \frac{\sum_i a_i f(x_i)}{\sum_i a_i}$ for a concave function $f$.

$f=log(x)$ is concave.

Thus,

$log(\frac{\sum_i a_i x_i}{\sum_i a_i})  \geq \frac{\sum_i a_i log(x_i)}{\sum_i a_i}$ $\implies$ $log(\frac{\sum_i a_i x_i}{\sum_i a_i})  \geq log((\Pi x_i^{a_i})^{\frac{1}{\sum_i a_i}})$ $\implies$ $\frac{\sum_i a_i x_i}{\sum_i a_i}  \geq (\Pi x_i^{a_i})^{\frac{1}{\sum_i a_i}}$

The last inequality is also the genereal weighted AM-GM inequality.

Answer (score 0):

It's just AM-GM:
$$ax+by\geq x^ay^b.$$
Done!

Comment: Is it "just AM-GM" or is it rather "weighted AM-GM in two variables"?

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown AM-GM it's the following. Let $x_i>0$, $\alpha_i>0$ and $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\alpha_i=1$. Prove that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\alpha_ix_i\geq\prod\limits_{i=1}^nx_i^{\alpha_i}$. In our case $n=2$.

Comment: That's the weighted AM-GM in $n$ variables. The plain AM-GM is the case $\alpha_i=1/n$.

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown Is the essence correct? Thank you!

Comment: Of course the essence is correct, but a novice when looking up AM-GM might see $(x_1+\cdots +x_n)/n\ge(x_1\cdots x_n)^{1/n}$ and wonder what that has to do with the problem at hand.

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown I think it's better to write AM-GM in the form, which I wrote. I think it's very useful.

Comment: Yes, the weighted AM-GM inequality is very useful.